# Erro localhost Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, entity-framework-6, localhost

O meu VS estava funcionando perfeitamente, hoje comprei e instalei o antivírus kaspersky, quando fui rodar um site ASP.NET(MVC) apareceu o seguinte erro:

> UNABLE TO START PROGRAM '' Uma operação não é
>   valida no estado atual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
 Como resolvo o problema?

Comment: Muda de navegador pra executar e mete o loko. rs Não é algo muito certo a se fazer mas na necessidade e falta de tempo funciona bem. Quando faço isso ele acaba meio que destravando o primeiro navegador.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verifique seu Firewall e tente mudar de porta, provabelmente um problema de ISS. Para configurar siga aqui o exemplo:

[image: CTRL+R]

[image: gerir foncionalidades do windows]

[image: escolher os programas]

[image: aplicar modificacoes]

[image: resultado do locahost]

Answer (score 1):

Uma outra opção até mais simples é parar o serviço do IIS e rodar novamente o projeto no Visual Studio que ao rodar (F5) novamente o seu projeto (por padrão) o visual studio vai subir uma nova instância do IIS.

Veja como parar o serviço de forma simples e fácil:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Tive o mesmo problema e resolvi rapidamente assim.